# Whats more 'expensive': having to do twice the URL requests or once downloading a larger JSON?

Tags: ios, json, nsurlsession

I'm just struggling whats the best interface for a JSON request having a **bad** internet connection with an ios device.

If I have the choice to style the API:

1. would it be better to have smaller JSONs and more requests, meaning to rather normalise the data and requesting it in a 'table manner'
2. or would it be better to have a denormalised JSON, that has most of the necessary data in it and therefore have less connections. Regarding the JSON size, I am talking about something like twenty 1k JSONs.

My guess is, that making a connecting to the server is more expensive than transmitting more data at once. Thats why I I'd go for denormalising the data on the server side.
Don't forget: I'm talking about a bad network connection (EDGE or lower).

Comment: With a RESTful API you could support both (Eg: allow `/things` and `/things/0`) then do benchmarks in the frontend.

Comment: You're mostly right, less connections would be more efficient. There's a lot of overhead with TCP connections so fewer would possibly be better.

Comment: Since the JSON is not a DB there is no reason for it to be normalized unless you are putting it into a normalized DB on the device. Send what the device needs. OTOH, is there a performance problem? If not don't try to optimize it. Kent Beck quote: "Do The Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work".

Comment: How you bundle the data should not affect how you hold it in a DB. Multiple connections on a slow network does not achieve anything IMHO other than to add extra network connection processing at both ends and to add extra packets onto the network to deal with TCP setup/tear down. If you assumed ~7 packets to open/close a TCP stream, thats 140 packets for 20 connections without sending data. There is also the setup latency for each one. Sending 20K should be no more than 20 packets. So 27 packets for 20K on one connection, 160 packets for 20 1K connections. My vote is for using one connection.